# Foursquare API error: Missing access credentials

Tags: android, foursquare

I'm making an Android app and am trying to use the [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/). I started to use the foursquare-recommended library, [easyFoursquare4Android](https://github.com/condesales/easyFoursquare4Android).

I registered my foursquare app at [https://foursquare.com/developers/apps](https://foursquare.com/oauth/). I Changed the `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` constant values in the *easyFoursquare4Android* library.

I tried to `getVenuesNearby()` and am getting this error message:

```
Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details.
```

I also am using the Facebook SDK and am using the same `Certificate fingerprint <SHA1>` that I'm using for Facebook.

Can I reuse the android key hash that I used with my Facebook app or do I have to make a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by logging the String I was sending to the API.

I never called `EasyFoursquare.requestAccess(this)` or `EasyFoursquareAsync.requestAccess(this)`, which requests the access to API by getting an oauth token.

So I never actually sent a `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` in my request.